# Plotting separate figures using list comprehension

Tags: list, matplotlib, plot, list-comprehension, figure

My current code produces overlapping figures for each element in the list *test*. How can I produce two separate figures using list comprehension? (Preferably using just one line of code).

```
test=[[1, 2, 3, 4],[5, 6, 7, 8]]
[plt.plot(test[k]) for k in range(0,2)]
```

Current output looks like this:

[image: Current output]

Comment: Note that this really isn't a good use case for list comprehension. To write it in one line, you could use `for k in range(0,2)`: plt.plot(test[k])`. Here list comprehension doesn't make things compacter, nor easier to read.

Comment: Understood. Thank you for making the useful comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the Matplotlib [Usage Guide](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/usage.html), `plt.plot` works the same way as the `ax.plot` graphing method:

> for each Axes graphing method, there is a corresponding function in the matplotlib.pyplot module that performs that plot on the "current" axes, creating that axes (and its parent figure) if they don't exist yet.

So when you run the list comprehension you have given as an example, the first `plt.plot` method call in the `for` loop creates a new [figure](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#parts-of-a-figure) object containing a child Axes object. Then, as noted in the Matplotlib Pyplot tutorial section on [working with multiple figures and axes](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html#working-with-multiple-figures-and-axes):

> MATLAB, and pyplot, have the concept of the current figure and the current axes. All plotting functions apply to the current axes.

This is why all the subsequent `plt.plot` calls in the loop are being plotted in the same figure. To draw the lines in separate figures, a new figure must be created for each `plt.plot` call, like so:

```
test = [[1, 2, 3, 4],[5, 6, 7, 8]]
for k in range(len(test)): plt.figure(), plt.plot(test[k])
```

Edit: based on the comment by JohanC (on the question), replaced list comprehension with a single-line compound statement. Even though this goes against [PEP 8 recommendations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations), it does indeed make the code more readable while meeting the one-line requirement.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation!